# Criptografar database CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, servidor

boa noite.

Peguei o barco andando aqui na empresa que entrei para continuar um sistema para uma empresa, em CodeIgniter conectado com um banco de dados SQLServer. Meu conhecimento em SQLServer e servidores é bem baixo, por isso tô apanhando um pouco.

O sistema está em um servidor e o banco de dados hospedado em outro. O cliente por ter medo de invasões, ou alguma coisa do tipo, queria que a conexão ficasse em outro servidor e criptografasse a senha de acesso ao banco, segundo ele.

Teria como eu fazer isso, colocar o arquivo database.php em outro servidor e meu sistema acessá-lo para buscar as informações e depois acessar o servidor com o banco, ou criptografar a senha de acesso ao banco?

Qualquer outra sugestão que puderem me dar, eu também estou disponível para ouvir e agradeceria muito.

Comment: Colocar o arquivo _database.php_ em outro servidor vai fazer o programa parar de funcionar. Fazer isso no mínimo não ajuda em nada. O _CodeIgniter_ tem opção para usar uma conexão criptografada: `'encrypt' => TRUE'` no _[database.php](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html)_. Mas a criptografia deve ser habilitada no `SQLServer`. Para garantir mais segurança no tráfego de dados e evitar interceptação de senhas use `HTTPS` (SSL/TLS no servidor web).

Comment: Uma coisa que recomendo é usar variáveis de ambiente, que dai ficará mais seguro sim, e quanto ao banco ficar em outro servidor pode ser por vários motivos, não só segurança, como processamento, distribuindo a carga entre servidores, assim a aplicação ganha performance. Da uma olhada nesse artigo que pode ajudar http://www.universidadecodeigniter.com.br/como-ler-variaveis-de-ambiente-no-codeigniter/

Comment: O arquivo _database.php_ já trabalha com variáveis de ambiente. Repito: **não há necessidade de mudar o _database.php_ pra outro servidor**. Isso só vai criar uma complicação desnecessária. Se o banco já está em outra máquina, ótimo. [Ative o SSL/TLS no banco](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/316898/how-to-enable-ssl-encryption-for-an-instance-of-sql-server-by-using-microsoft-management-console) e use HTTPS nas conexões com o _browser_.

Comment: O cliente provavelmente nem sabe o que está falando (como na maioria das vezes). Ele acha que assim é a melhor maneira de prevenir ataques, mas não é por aí. Daqui a pouco ele vai querer usar um webservice só para isso!

Comment: Se o problema do cliente é esse medo de ser atacado, seria interessante então disponibilizar uma senha para a base de dados com um acesso mais restrito.